# My C# List is not letting me add data to it when I have a List collection within properties of a class

Tags: c#, .net, list, collections

What am i doing wrong with this ?

1. Do I need instantiate List of Book ( other class ) ?

   ```
   clsP.Books = new List<Book>();
   ```
2. This is the line i get the error in linqpad

   > 'UserQuery.Book' does not contain a constructor that takes 3 arguments

   ```
   var book1 = new Book("Neuromancer", "William Gibson", "Science Fiction");
   ```

This is the complete code , what is the problem?

```
void Main()
{       
    var clsPList = new List<clsPerson>();       
    var clsP = new clsPerson();
    clsP.FirstName = "jack";
    clsP.LastName = "barker";
    clsP.Gender = "male";       

    //clsP.Books = new List<Book>();
    var book1 = new Book("Neuromancer", "William Gibson", "Science Fiction");

    clsP.Books.Add(book1);
    clsPList.Add(clsP);         
    clsPList.Dump();                        
}

public class clsPerson
{
    public string FirstName;
    public string LastName;
    public string Gender;
    public List<Book> Books = new List<Book>();
}

public class Book
{
    public string Title;
    public string Author;
    public string Genre;        
}
```

Comment: The book class has only the default constructor with zero arguments.

Comment: It doesn't have a constructor that takes any arguments, so just initialize the properties like you do with the clsPerson object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is correct. You need to either provide `Book` with a valid constructor...

```
public class Book
{
    public Book(string title, string author, string genre)
    {
        Title = title;
        Author = author;
        Genre = genre;
    }

    public string Title;
    public string Author;
    public string Genre;
}
```

... or just assign to the properties directly:

```
var book1 = new Book {
                         Title = "Neuromancer",
                         Author = "William Gibson",
                         Genre = "Science Fiction"
                     };
```

Comment: Or assign the properties after the class construction, just like you're doing with the `clsPerson` class.

Comment: Method must have a return type

Comment: `public Book(string title, string author, string genre)`

Answer (score 0):

Exactly as the error says, Book doesn't have a constructor taking 3 arguments.
Your options are either Instantiate the properties inline eg.

```
var book1 = new Book() 
{
    Title = "Neuromancer", 
    Author = "William Gibson", 
    Genre "Science Fiction"
};
```

Or declare a constructor on book eg.

```
public class Book
{
    public string Title;
    public string Author;
    public string Genre;  

    public Book (string title, string author, string genre)
    {
        Title = title;
        Author = author;
        Genre = genre;
    }      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need instantiate List of Book ( other class )

In this case, you don't need it, because you initialize `Books` field with an empty list:

```
public List<Book> Books = new List<Book>();
```

Without this assignment field would be initialized with default value `null`.

> list is the line i get the error

You haven't specified any constructors in your `Book` class. So only default *parameterless* constructor is available. Either use object initialzer:

```
var book1 = new Book { 
     Title = "Neuromancer",
     Author = "William Gibson",
     Genre = "Science Fiction"
    };
```

or create constructor with three parameters and then your code will be compiled without errors

```
public class Book
{
    public Book(string title, string author, string genre)
    {
        Title = title;
        Author = author;
        Genre = genre;
    }

    public string Title;
    public string Author;
    public string Genre;        
}
```

One more note - it's better to use *properties* instead of public fields:

```
public string Title { get; set; }
```

Comment: if i change from public fields to properties like this  `public string Title {get; set;}`    can /should i also change the Book constructor as well?